# XCode Adding dSYM file for a framework with debug information in it

Tags: xcode, frameworks, crash, gdb, debug-symbols

I am using a third party framework with XCode, ( say thirdparty.framework ) which has been built with debug information. Also, they provided a .dSYM file along with it.

However, this third party framework ends up crashing in a particular instance, and on running XCode's gdb's 'bt full' command, I end up getting the 'No Symbol table info available' message for the calls made once inside in the framework.

How can I get the entire info for the function calls made ? i.e: locals, proper function names, etc.

Thanks !

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this?

Comment: Yes, I added the dSYM file to the frameworks folder of the project, recompiled the library with debug symbols on and it worked.

Comment: Did you really mean dSYM *file*?  On my Mac, it is a folder, containing `Contents/Info.plist` and `Contents/Resources/DWARF/<binary.name>` which is smaller than the actual binary.